# Ansible: vmware parallel deployment with multiple Vcenter

Tags: ansible

I’m trying to write playbook that will create 3 vm's on 3 ESXI servers from template through Vcenter with Ansible vmware_guest module.

The problem is that i have 3  different Vcenters with 3 ESXI hosts on each and playbook must create all the vm's on all ESXI host in parallel.

i tried with loop, but loop do it step by step.

Here is my version of playbook as of now.

I will be very thankful if someone helps me with that :)

```html
---
# create a new VM from a template

- name: VM from template
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: 10.0.0.1
    vcenter_user: john.doe
    vcenter_pass: Passw0rd
    vmtemplate: test-teplate
    name: "newvm2"
    notes: Ansible Test
  tasks:
    - name: Create VM from template
      vmware_guest:
        validate_certs: False
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        esxi_hostname: "{{ item.esxhost }}"
        datacenter: Datacenter1
        folder: templates
        name: "{{ name }}"
        template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
        disk:
          - size_gb: 100
            datastore: "{{ item.datastore }}"
        wait_for_ip_address: False
        state: present
      register: newvm2
      loop:
        - {esxhost: '10.0.46.142', datastore: 'Datastore_XXX'}
        - {esxhost: '10.0.46.143', datastore: 'Datastore_ZZZ'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create them in parallel by dynamically adding each ESX host to the inventory, it would look something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        hostname: '{{item.esxhost}}'
        groups: vms
        esxhost:   '{{ item.esxhost }}'
        datastore: '{{ item.datastore }}'
      loop:
         - {esxhost: '10.0.46.142', datastore: 'Datastore_XXX'}
         - {esxhost: '10.0.46.143', datastore: 'Datastore_ZZZ'}

- name: VM from template
  hosts: vms
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: 10.0.0.1
    vcenter_user: john.doe
    vcenter_pass: Passw0rd
    vmtemplate: test-teplate
    name: "newvm2"
    notes: Ansible Test
  tasks:
    - name: Create VM from template
      vmware_guest:
        validate_certs: False
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxhost }}"
        datacenter: Datacenter1
        folder: templates
        name: "{{ name }}"
        template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
        disk:
          - size_gb: 100
            datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
        wait_for_ip_address: False
        state: present
      register: newvm2
```

You can use the same principle to create all 9 VMs at the same time.

Comment: Can't we just put all that in the inventory, rather than that `add_host` stuff?  Playbooks should have no host-specific information, so that they will be portable between inventories.

Comment: I agree, if possible it should come from directly from the inventory, there are however some use cases for adding hosts dynamically, like when the data comes from inputs from a Tower template etc. I am unsure what the use case is here.

Comment: I submit that that is a bad use case.  Optimally, there should be a single "source of truth" which either IS the inventory (held in a version control system such as Subversion or Git), or a spreadsheet or database from which the inventory can be generated.  (In the case of a dynamic inventory, the "source of truth" would hold counts and specs for the VMs in `group_vars/all`.)  Only for throw-away VMs should such information come from user input, but even there, it's just as easy to make a new inventory in Tower.

Comment: Could you please show how the example with this playbook with putting all the hosts to inventory ?

Comment: Also i need to have different name for vm's. Is It Possible ?

Comment: Where are the different names coming from?